# C++で16進数の文字列と、16進数の数値の相互変換の方法を知りたい

Tags: c++

C++初心者です。
[以下のようなコード](https://www.delftstack.com/ja/howto/cpp/string-to-hex-cpp/)で、文字列を16進数文字列に変換しました。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

using std::cout; using std::endl;
using std::string; using std::hex;
using std::stringstream;

int main() {
    string s1 = "This will be converted to hexadecimal";
    string s2;
    stringstream ss;

    cout << "string: " << s1 << endl;

    for (const auto& item : s1) {
        ss << hex << int(item);
    }
    s2 = ss.str();
    cout << s2 << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

上記のコードを実行すると、変数`s2`は`"546869732077696c6c20626520636f6e76657274656420746f2068657861646563696d616c"`であることが分かります。

その後に、その変数`s2`を16進数文字列を、16進数の数値に変換して、16進数同士の足し算の計算などをし、再度16進数の文字列に戻したいのですが、どうしたら出来るのでしょうか？
C++の16進数の数値というのはint型なのかunsignedInt型なのかなど、そのあたりから分からないので知りたいです。

Comment: 参考までになぜ「16進数同士の足し算の計算などをし」たいのでしょうか？ あまり意味のある行為には思えませんでした。

Comment: 特に意味はないのですが、ど素人なりにコードの難読化的なことをやる方法の1つとして考えていました

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++言語に用意されている[数値型は64bit程度](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)です。
64bitというと、16進数文字列で8文字、元の文字列では4文字分でしかありません。

それ以上の桁数の計算を行うのであれば、ご自身で自作するか、外部のライブラリを使用することになります。行いたい演算にもよりますが、例えば[Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)なんかが使えるかもしれません。

---

ちなみに、[先の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/75249/4236)で

> C++言語において文字とは文字コードを値に持つ数値でもあります。

説明しました。16進数文字列に対して演算を行う必要はなく、元の文字列を数値として扱い、直接演算した方が効率的です。（そうだとしても、64bitで8文字分ですが…。）

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。C++で扱える数値型のサイズについても知らなかったためとても参考になりました。

Answer (score 1):

16進数文字列という中間的な値を取らずに、直接`std::string`と`std::vector<char>`の間を変換した方が良いのでは？

文字列から文字(数値)の配列(vector)への変換：
[How to copy std::string into std::vector? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8263926/9014308)

> ```
> std::string str = "hello";
> std::vector<char> data(str.begin(), str.end());
> ```

文字(数値)の配列(vector)から文字列への変換：
[std::vectorをstd::stringやchar*に変換する](https://gin0606.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/12/12/162218)

> `std::vector<char>`型の変数`vecChar`があるとする。
>
> ```
> // -> std::string
> std::string stdString(vecChar.begin(), vecChar.end());
> ```

---

`C++の16進数の数値というのはint型なのかunsignedInt型なのか`という疑問は少しずれていて、`数値`というのが`型`を持っているのではなく、それぞれの`型`で取り扱える`数値の範囲`が定義されている訳です。それはコンパイラとかOSとかオプション指定とかの条件で決まるか変えられたりします。

で、おそらく相応しい問いは`C++の1文字`で扱える数値の型は何か？ということでしょう。
こちらに資料があります。
[string - cpprefjp - C++日本語リファレンス](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/string.html)

> char_traits    文字特性(class template)
>
> basic_string   汎用文字型の文字列(class template)
> string マルチバイト文字列(type-alias)

[std::basic_string - cpprefjp - C++日本語リファレンス](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/string/basic_string.html)

> string char型文字列。ASCII、UTF-8等のマルチバイト文字列や、バイト配列として使用する。

[std::char_traits - cpprefjp - C++日本語リファレンス](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/string/char_traits.html)

`std::string`の各文字は`std::char`で、コンパイラやオプションとかOSに依存するでしょうが、だいたい8bitでしょう。符号の有無は環境依存でしょうか。